# How to use mouseover funtion on multiple cells?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple booking page. Already booked places belong to class "notAvailable". I want to use ajax to query username who booked certain slot. How can I achieve that?

```
 $mydb = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');
    $myquery = "SELECT day, time FROM reserve";
    $result = mysqli_query($mydb, $myquery);

    $data_array = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {    
    $data_array[$row['day']][] = $row['time'];  
}
$arr2=array('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday');

foreach($arr2 as $v)
{    
    if(array_key_exists($v,$data_array))
    {
        $arr4[$v]=$data_array[$v];
    }
}

$times = ['08:00', '09:00','10:00', '11:00', '12:00',  '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00'];
?>
```

I used fetch_assoc funtion to get all booked slots from database just in once
And here I need ajax query to get username for each booked cell when mouse is on the cell.

```
 <TABLE class="myTimetable"> 
  <THEAD>
    <TR>
      <TH></TH>
      <TH>Monday</TH>
      <TH>Tuesday</TH>
      <TH>Wednesday</TH>
      <TH>Thursday</TH>
      <TH>Friday</TH>     
    </TR>
  </THEAD>
  <TBODY>
 <?php 

foreach($times as $time)
{?>
    <tr>
    <?php

        $nome=$nome+1;
        echo $nome;
        echo "<td>$time</td>";
        foreach($arr4 as $aa => $bb)
        {            
            if(in_array($time , $bb))
            {
                echo "<td class='notAvailable'></td>";
            }
            else{
                echo "<td class='available'>mine</td>";
            }
        }
    ?>
    </tr>
<?php
}

?>
</TBODY>
  </TABLE>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, what does it has to do with mouse over?

Comment: Query above will create 9 time slots for each day of the week (Monday-Friday). So when I bring mouse over certain booked cell (hover) it should show me who booked that place using ajax.

Comment: @Tabriz You want to kick off an AJAX call on-hover? You would need to create a listener for an on-hover event to do this. This question is overly broad IMO. Please try to implement an on-hover listener event that kicks off the AJAX function and then post a question about troubleshooting that if you can't get it to work. Stack overflow is not asking people to write code and solve things for you without trying yourself. Hopefully you understand the nuance.

Answer (score 0):

I see no querys for the who reserved the time slot, but to show the data you can do something like this

```
<?php
 $byHow = "for now unknown";
 echo '<td class="notAvailable" data-by-who="'.$byWho.'">timeslot</td>';
```

in javascript

```
$('.notAvailable').on('mouseover',function(){
   alert($(this).data('byWho'));
});
```

Comment: I tried this query to get username but it does not work. if(in_array($time , $bb))
            {
                echo "<td class='notAvailable'></td>";
                $myquery1 = "SELECT user, time FROM reserve where time='$time' and day='$aa'";
                $result1 = mysqli_query($mydb, $myquery1);
                $row1=mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
                $xloc= $row1['user'];
                
                
            }
            else{
                echo "<td class='available'></td>";
            }